# Program for hallow triangle: * pattern

Tags: java

I'm trying to print this pattern, but I'm unable to get print * in the last lines

```
                       *
                   *        *
               *                 *
          *                           *   
     *        *        *        *       *
```

but  I end up with this, the last line is the problem

```
                       *
                   *        *
               *                 *
          *                           *   
     *                                   *
```

---

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= m - i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
        if (k == 1 || k == i - 1)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ware almost there. You just need to include condition to write `*` if `k` handles last row, in other words `i == m` so your

```
if (k == 1 || k == i - 1)
```

should look more like

```
if (k == 1 || k == i - 1 || i == m)
```

Another thing is that you need to guarantee that regardless if you print `*` or not, two characters must be added to row, which means `"* "` or `"  "`. Currently you are only printing `"*"` or `"  "` which is not what you want. Change

```
if (k == 1 || k == i - 1 || i == m) 
    System.out.print("*");
System.out.print("  ");
```

to

```
if (k == 1 || k == i - 1 || i == m) 
    System.out.print("*");
else 
    System.out.print(" ");
System.out.print("  ");
```

or maybe simpler

```
if (k == 1 || k == i - 1 || i == m) 
    System.out.print("* ");
else 
    System.out.print("  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        import java.util.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        class Spiral
          {
         public static void main(String[] args)
                {    
          int m=12;
          for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
              for (int j = 1; j <= m - i; j++) 
               {
              System.out.print(" ");
                }
          for (int k = 1; k < i; k++) {
           if (k == 1 || k == i-1 )
            System.out.print("*");

          System.out.print("  ");
               if(i==m)
               {
            for(int n=2;n<12;n++)
              {
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.print(" ");

          break;
              }
           }
      System.out.println(" ");
       }

      }
   }
```

[image]